# Calculating the volume of a surfboard

Tags: calculus, geometry, 3d

I'm building a website for a client in which customers can customise the shape of their board (curvature, length, width, thickness, and so forth) and the client has asked if we can calculate the volume of the board and display it in response to the user's customisations.

This sounds like scary advanced calculus and/or differential geometry territory, but I said I'd try to find out the feasibility of doing so nonetheless. I'll mainly be using a set of bezier curves as a baseline to define the board shape and there will of course be curves in all dimensions. The nose will sometimes come to a point and other times be rounded off. The tail will come in a variety of shapes, including being rounded, coming to a point, or even having an inverted "fish tail" shape.

Where would I even start with calculating the volume of a surfboard like this? I'd be looking to represent the volume in litres.

**Edit**: I'm guessing I'd need to break the board down into chunks that minimise the number of simultaneous curves and calculate them individually. I'm thinking maybe it's also easier to calculate the volumes of each chunk relative to a uniform enclosing box and subtract each value from the total box volume to get the final volume...

Answer (score 1):

If you use any modeling software, it probably has a volume function in it. Otherwise, one approach which I used before is to approximate the surface with a triangulation, then used calculated the volume from the tetrahedra formed by each face and the origin (some triangles have to be summed in, while others have to subtracted out, but if you set it up right, that happens automatically). I presented a paper on the method (which I also used to calculate all mass properties) to SAWE, the Society of Allied Weight Engineers. I could send you a copy if you want. The volume you get this way will only be an approximation, with how close depending on how fine of a triangulation you use. One other issue is that I get the triangulation from an existing modeling package, so I am not versed in technique for triangulation.

You can calculate the volume directly from the Bezier curves, but that is definitely messier. How to do it would depend very much on what modeling techniques you use.

Comment: Thanks, the triangulation method sounds doable; would love to see your paper on the subject! axefrog at gmail dot com if you prefer. I'm not using any external software; this will all be custom rendered as vector outlines on an HTML5 canvas; my data will primarily be bezier curves, adapted from a set of real world units.

Comment: I've sent it. The particular formula you need is $V = \frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_i V_{i1} \cdot V_{i2} \times V_{i3}$, where $V_{i1}, V_{i2}, V_{i3}$ are the vertices of triangle i, ordered so that the vector $(V_{i2} - V_{i1}) \times (V_{i3} - V_{i1})$ points outward from the board (this is critical).

Comment: Great, thanks for that!

Comment: You can improve accuracy by using some point in the middle of the interior of the board, rather than using the origin (which might be outside). This reduces numerical problems.

Comment: True. While in exact arithmetic the point used as origin doesn't matter, computational error will be least when its near the centroid of the board.